# ggplot2 and ggdist: Skip plotting distributions where group has 1 obs. in multiple boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have issues using a combination of `ggdist::stat_halfeye` with `ggplot:geom_boxplot` in a plot containing groups with 1 obs.

To replicate the intended outcome:

```
# Intended outcome
data(iris)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Length")) + 
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    adjust = 1, 
    width = .4, 
    .width = 0, 
    justification = -.7, 
    point_colour = NA
  )+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.2) + 
  geom_boxplot(
    width = .4, 
    outlier.shape = NA
  ) +
  geom_point(
    size = 1,
    alpha = .3,
    position = position_jitter(seed = 1, width = .1)
  ) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = prettyNum) + 
  annotation_logticks(short=unit(0.15, "cm"), mid=unit(0.25, "cm"), long=unit(0.35,"cm"), sides="l", outside = TRUE) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(margin = margin(t = 5)), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1), colour = "red")+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", aes(group=1), colour = "red")

p1 # Looks good
```

[image: Intended outcome]

To replicate the error when one group contains 1 obs.:

```
# Errors
iris2 <- iris[iris$Species != "setosa",]
iris2 <- rbind(iris2,iris[iris$Species == "setosa",][1,])

p2 <- ggplot(iris2, aes_string(x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Length")) + 
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    adjust = 1, 
    width = .4, 
    .width = 0, 
    justification = -.7, 
    point_colour = NA
  )+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.2) + 
  geom_boxplot(
    width = .4, 
    outlier.shape = NA
  ) +
  geom_point(
    size = 1,
    alpha = .3,
    position = position_jitter(seed = 1, width = .1)
  ) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = prettyNum) + 
  annotation_logticks(short=unit(0.15, "cm"), mid=unit(0.25, "cm"), long=unit(0.35,"cm"), sides="l", outside = TRUE) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(margin = margin(t = 5)), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1), colour = "red")+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", aes(group=1), colour = "red")

p2 # Not so good now - ggdist::stat_halfeye gives warning:
# Warning message:
# Computation failed in `stat_sample_slabinterval()`:
# need at least 2 points to select a bandwidth automatically
```

[image: Error]

As can be seen, the `ggdist::stat_halfeye()` has been unable to calculate the distribution for the first group, and instead of skipping, and moving to the next, it has stopped for all following groups.

How can I permit `ggdist::stat_halfeye()` to skip groups with 1 obs., without skipping the remainder?

Comment: I've tried to run your code but even when using ggplot and ggdist, the function `base_breaks()` is missing.

Comment: Apologies, small oversight. Function ```base_breaks()``` now removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before use `ggplot(.....)`, filter first and then draw plot will work. `base_breaks()` doesn't exist, so I remove that.

```
  ggplot(aes_string(x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Length"), data = iris2 ) + 
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(aes_string(x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Length"), data = iris2%>%
                         group_by(Species) %>%
                         filter(n() > 1) ,
    adjust = 1, 
    width = .4, 
    .width = 0, 
    justification = -.7, 
    point_colour = NA
  )+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width = 0.2) + 
  geom_boxplot(
    width = .4, 
    outlier.shape = NA
  ) +
  geom_point(
    size = 1,
    alpha = .3,
    position = position_jitter(seed = 1, width = .1)
  ) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10", labels = prettyNum) + 
  annotation_logticks(short=unit(0.15, "cm"), mid=unit(0.25, "cm"), long=unit(0.35,"cm"), sides="l", outside = TRUE) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(margin = margin(t = 5)), 
        axis.text.y=element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1), colour = "red")+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", aes(group=1), colour = "red")
```

[image: skip]

Comment: This works, although ideally I would still like to keep the groups with 1 obs. for the ```stat_boxplot``` (really just median line) and ```geom_point``` as this better visualizes the entire dataset

Comment: @micx274 I edit my code. add `aes()` inside `stat_halfeye` with filtered data will work

Comment: brilliant and thank you! Marked as answer.